Why 2nd plot doesnt fit with plot1 format if is already created?
I´m trying to plot a second object inside a figure that contains values readed from a .CSV file with pandas, and detect how many days this file contains and its hours to compare days with days and from start to end hours in every day
self.excel2 = pandas.read_csv(self.Doc2, sep="\t", encoding="utf-16")
self.excel2.columns = ["Hour", "Date", "Value"]

for Hour in range(self.DayEndsValue1[0], self.DayEndsValue1[1]): 
    ValueX = self.excel1.loc[Hour, "Hour"]
    self.Plot1X.append(ValueX)

for Value in range(self.DayEndsValue1[0], self.DayEndsValue1[1]):
    ValueY = self.excel1.loc[Value, "Value"]
    self.Plot1Y.append(ValueY)

Append readed values to a list and then show the plot, same steps for graph the first plot.
How it looks at first 2 Plots, Same Day
But when i change the day from the drop down menu looks like thisDifferent Days, plost show two times xtick values
i want to show this 2 plots at same figure ex: if day 26 starts at 11AM and ends at 23:55:99 and day 27 starts from 0 AM and ends at 23:59:99 how to draw this 2 plots at same format at same time space, 2 plot with diferent dimensions X and Y
Why doesnt format at same time in 24 hours format if is already formated?
Am i doing something wrong to formatted this?
I tried to use the datetime.strptime to format the X Value and send it to a new clean list just like this:
for Hour2 in range(self.DayEndsValue2[Index2], self.DayEndsValue2[Index2 + 1]):
            ValueX2 = self.excel2.loc[Hour2, "Hour"]
            self.Plot2X.append(ValueX2)
            hour = dt.datetime.strptime(ValueX2, '%H:%M:%S')
            self.HoursDay2.append(hour.hour)
        self.returnedList2 = list(set(self.HoursDay2))

Also tried to do after plot use the AutoDateLocation and set_major_formatter from mdates but nothing happens
    self.FiguraGeneral = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7), clear=True)
        self.FiguraGeneral.clear()

        self.FigureBoth = self.FiguraGeneral.add_subplot(111)
        self.FigureBoth.plot(self.Plot1X, self.Plot1Y, color="b", label="Presion 1")
        self.FigureBoth.scatter(self.Plot2X, self.Plot2Y, color="r", label="Presion 2")

        self.FigureBoth.set_title("PRESIONES")
        self.FigureBoth.set_xlabel("Hora")
        self.FigureBoth.set_ylabel("Presion Ms")

        locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=12, maxticks=24)
        plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
        #plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

Attached last example: Hours readed from day 27
Here is the code to gen this plots: Scripts on Drive

Hi! Could you edit the question to include a link to (part of) the data so that it will be possible to reproduce the code?

Done, put them in a drive all code is in there.

I have tested the code, and noticed that also if you try to change the hour of the day selection (Desde, Hasta) the plot is screwed up. There is likely something wrong with the indexing of the x values. My suggestion is that you test your logic in a cleaner script (no GUII, just plots) trying to plot data from different days in the format you desire. A general advice is to include waaay more comments, possibly in English. I am Italian so I understand a bit of Spanish, but coding in a language that is not English will cause part of this community not to understand (and thus help!) you

I dont think the plots is the problem, working with a single plot if you change the hours of the day (Desde,Hasta) the plots shows correctly. As you can see i already update this scripts if you can check it would be great, i added some comments to it. (Make sure to check a single bool when read). Thanks for you help
Im considering to separate each functionallity in "BothPressions" but i think would be the same result because of the format

I think i found the solution, i will back to give feedback of it, ill set all til its all working!

According to this Stack Overflow post, the x-axis needs to be formatted with a strptime extracting the values from the document to Excel for plotting. Then, the plot is already done but with no format. Finally, plot with two figures using:

set_major_formatter
set_major_locator

This is my working code:
        for Value in range(self.DayEndsValue1[Index], self.DayEndsValue1[Index + 1]):
        ValueY = self.excel1.loc[Value, "Value"]
        self.Plot1Y.append(ValueY)

    for Hour2 in range(self.DayEndsValue2[Index2], self.DayEndsValue2[Index2 + 1]):
        ValueX = dt.datetime.strptime(self.excel2.loc[Hour2, "Hour"], "%H:%M:%S")
        self.Plot2X.append(ValueX)
        self.HoursDay2.append(ValueX.hour)
    self.returnedList2 = list(set(self.HoursDay2))

    for Value2 in range(self.DayEndsValue2[Index2], self.DayEndsValue2[Index2 + 1]):
        ValueY2 = self.excel2.loc[Value2, "Value"]
        self.Plot2Y.append(ValueY2)


    fig, FigA = self.FiguraGeneral = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7), sharex=True)
    FigA.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
    FigA.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=12, maxticks=30))

    FigA.plot(self.Plot1X, self.Plot1Y, color="b", label="Presion 1")
    FigA.scatter(self.Plot2X, self.Plot2Y, color="r", label="Presion 2")

    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()



Great you managed to find a solution by yourself!
